# Is it ok to turn off windows 10 Firewall

Tags: windows-10, firewall

I am a novice PC guy for many years.

I recently had file-share issues with other PCs on my network. I called a repair center and they came out and essentially turned off the windows 10 firewall and said that I don't need it since the router and Internet provider have enough firewalls (for the amount of $90 for 15 minutes of work).

Is it correct to turn off the firewall ?

Comment: This question is highly subjective to opinions, but if they would do this to me, I would definitely not agree with it. Its a "Quick fix". If disabling the windows firewall solves the problem, then that only means the problem is located. By setting up the firewall correctly, the problem can be easily fixed too. To answer your question if its okay: that depends on a lot of things. If you have a router with open wifi, its definitely not okay. But a router does provide an extra layer of security.

Comment: As for the sharing issues, its most likely due to the network being identified as public, rather than home or work, and settings for advanced file sharing. The wrong settings will make firewall block connections. So with that in mind, the solution provided is not the correct one, and should not be accepted.

Comment: I agree with @LPChip. I'd be concerned turning off your firewall was the charged resolution. Multiple OS firewalls is usually not really a problem because a specific vendor will (usually) disable WIndows firewall and the security center will identify a firewall is installed. E.g. Install McAfee and try and turn on Windows firewall (it won't let you). Firewalls at different layers of your network, however, is completely different and are often configured for specific purposes at the points they secure. I'd investigate more thoroughly the cause as to why it doesn't work with the firewall on.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not an acceptable resolution.

Windows Firewall may have been viewed as an optional component in Windows XP Service Pack 2, and I've been told that, at times, even Microsoft suggested turning it off to help resolve issues.  However, now-a-days that's different.  If you run without Windows Firewall, there can be problems as some components of Microsoft Windows have now started to rely on the functionality of the Windows Firewall being active.

This includes setting up new printers that get shared, and installing commands from PowerShell using the built-in Windows store.  Those are just the issues I've been told within the last week, as a leader at a computer support company.

Disabling a core component of Windows that provides security is not the right answer.  The Windows firewall is designed to protect against attacks that may come from the Internet, as well as elsewhere on your intranet/LAN.  The hardware firewall you may (and should!) have outside of your computer can only protect against some of those attacks.  This company has introduced a vulnerability.

> the router and provider have enough firewalls.

Absolutely not.  Home-grade routers have proven, time and time again, that they have not been designed to have firewall capabilities that provide sufficient protection.  Maybe they provide sufficient protection in theory, but they have routinely proven to fail to succeed at preventing remote attacks from working.  This has been true amongst *ALL* of the manufacturers that I've become aware of.  Absolutely do not rely on home-grade routers (or even business-grade routers) to be acting as a firewall.  Get a dedicated hardware firewall.

As for the provider, I have not heard of sufficient protection being offered by Internet Service Providers.  Many don't provide such protection at all; some do, but only minimally and if they were really effective, then there'd be a lot less stories about successful Internet attacks.  Whether it is even realistically possible for ISP's to block most Internet attacks, other than much (but certainly not all) of spam, is highly questionable.  Whether they actually are effective at blocking most Internet-based attacks is absolutely not questioned, and the answer is absolutely: no.

You were fed a line, and it doesn't stand up to technical scrutiny.  I do like the take from LPChip's comments: They have done part of their job by narrowing down the problem, and then they should have shown an iota of technical competence by properly setting up the Windows Firewall product to work.  Instead they've taken an extremely improper approach that has introduced a gaping hole in security.  By doing so, they have done you a terrible disservice.

Comment: The going rate in my area is $89-$110 for an hour of work being charged to businesses, with discounts for those who provide repeat business.  (This is based on multiple IT businesses I've become familiar with.)  You're definitely not getting a tremendous bargain.  However, I'm not including that as part of the answer as financial analysis is really off-topic for the types of questions that SuperUser is intended to be about.

Comment: Keep in mind, this is the total price. There's likely also a transport fee involved, for getting the mechanic to the location and back to the office.

Comment: @LPChip : Keep in mind, a lot of such services do not even involve having a mechanic go on location.  Remote support has proven to be more cost effective in many, many scenarios.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm in the business myself, and I provide remote support daily. I wonder because in the question, they mention: "They came out" which to me reads as: they came over.

Comment: @LPChip: Oversight on my part.  I withdraw my comment.  (I was rushed... in such conditions, likely would have been wiser not to act at all.)  I thank you for the politeness of your response.

Answer (score -1):

The repair people are correct as regarding the firewall
(no comment about the $90), but only if you have taken the following
precautions as regarding your router:

- Changed its password from the default one (which everybody knows)
- Disabled sign-on from the Internet (most probably this is already the case)
- Checked regularly for the latest firmware update (many routers do that
  automatically when you enter their main page).

Do not assume that the ISP has any useful firewall for your protection.

Comment: I think that the likes of WannaCry proves that every node needs a firewall, regardless how well a network's edge is protected.

Comment: @Twisty: WannaCry used an SMBv1 vulnerability. SMBv1 ought to be turned off in the router, and how would the attacker bypass the router? After all, all ports on the router are normally closed unless turned on manually or by PnP. The Windows firewall itself will therefore only serve to block internal programs from accessing the outside, so not of much use. The leaked NSA tools included router exploits, but these have been quickly patched by most serious router manufacturers, which is why I counseled care about firmware updates.

Comment: And in any case, no firewall will protect from attacks via the browser, which are the most common and dangerous ones. Hackers have all but abandoned all other kinds of attacks - WannaCry was an exception, which is maybe why it was so successful.

Comment: my point is that an internal node can be compromised, despite a protected edge, and that putting all your eggs into the basket of "my network is protected by the router" is contrary to the practice of defense in depth.

Comment: @Twisty: No, not "my network is protected by the router" but rather: The router is as good or better than Windows' firewall. A firewall is far from offering full protection and IMHO is not even the most important one for the computer. But traditionally, most people will cry out in horror against any such advice, although it is rather outdated today.

Comment: I agree that a network firewall is "more" important than the Windows firewall. I disagree with disabling the Windows firewall because not all threats are on the outside of the router. Of course, the Windows firewall can't stop *all* threats from within the network either, but that doesn't condemn it to being disabled. It's simply one of the *layers* of a well-protected network.